# Saving a checkbox value or name on firebase/firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, input, checkbox, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a social network project, in which people have to select favorite topics, i am trying to store the value(or name) of a checkbox once it's checked, so it can be called and shown later on.

Is there a way I can store this in firestore as part of a user profile? Right now the account creation section allows me to store the name, email and username of the user, but I'm not sure how to store the checkbox value.

Thanks! I've been learning js for a few months, so please don't be so harsh on me, maybe this is a basic them i've skipped or didn't understand correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're asking how to store additional (user) information in Firestore? If so the typical design pattern is to create a collection called */users* with child documents that use the user id (uid) as the documentID. From there, you can store any additional information within that users document about that user.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches for this, I think the most simple would be to save the topics as booleans inside the user. You could add the booleans with the name of the topic and if they are checked just add them as true.

Alternatively, you could just add an array of topics of interest for the user and then just add more information to the array if the user tries to update it later. You can just display the checkbox as marked if the topic is inside the array.

I hope you find this useful, and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I actually used the second solution, my first approach was booleans, but it was way easier with and array!